# obtain ISO8601 format string in python

Tags: python, iso8601, python-datetime

Is there a way to obtain a `strftime` string corresponding to the ISO8601 format in python?

i.e. I'm looking for something that returns `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"` (assuming I copied that correctly).

In practice I would apply that for `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter` (that didn't format in ISO8601 out of the box for me and I didn't find a corresponding flag in its documentation).

Comment: Are you looking for [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) or do you need the actual format string?

Comment: I'm looking for the actual format string. (the corner I ran into is matplotlib LineCollection, which doesn't handle datetime objects in arrays, so I converted them with date2num to float, which then the DateFormatter can still format with a strftime format string, but which by itself doesn't have an isoformat method)

Comment: looks to me like that might not even be possible. `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"` is pretty close except for the `:` separator in the timezone `'2018-02-13T10:04:02.710511+03:00'` vs `'2018-02-13T10:04:02.710511+0300'` (and I don't see "omit microseconds" in the strftime docs)